# firebase notification doesn't recibe swit 3

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am implementing push notification from firebase, in my implementation i receive the token from send the notification, but when i test in my firebase console the message is send succesfully but i never receive the message in mi app, this is my app delegate, who can be the problem?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import GoogleMaps
import FBSDKCoreKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("******")
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            //FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        FirebaseApp.configure()
       //
        let tokenChido = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("\(tokenChido)")

        return true

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        var token = ""
        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
        }
        print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)

    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!
            , annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        return handled
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
         let tipo =  notification.request.content.userInfo["gcm.notification.tipo"] as? String
        print(notification.request.content.userInfo["gcm.notification.tipo"])
        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
        let title : String = d["title"] as! String
        if tipo == "2"{
            let manager = DbManager(delegate2: UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
            manager.setMakeProfesional()
        }
        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
         self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)
        completionHandler([])

    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let dict = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
        let body : String = d["body"] as! String
        let title : String = d["title"] as! String
        let tipo =  response.notification.request.content.userInfo["gcm.notification.tipo"] as? String
        if tipo == "2"{
            let manager = DbManager(delegate2: UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
            manager.setMakeProfesional()
        }
        let manager = DbManager(delegate2: UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
        manager.setMakeProfesional()
        print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
        print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }

    func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Union")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
         print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
}
```

and in my info.plst i have the property FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = false

Comment: Have you tried to test that on Simulator or real device? BTW Simulator doesn't support Push Notifications

Comment: yes i try in a real devices, ios 10 and 11